# Error while attempting to combine two booleans together

Tags: android, boolean

I am attempting to code a simple boolean function, and yet it is outputting a strange error.

```
private int Judge(int Speed, int ViolationLimit, int SpeedLimit, int ExceedInstance) {
    if (Speed>=1 && Speed=<SpeedLimit) {
        ExceedInstance += 1;
    }
    return ExceedInstance;
}
```

I typed the above and it came up with the error,
"Operator && cannot be applied to boolean, int"
But I don't understand the error message. What does it mean by 'boolean, int'?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change to this `Speed>=1 && Speed<=SpeedLimit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong logical operator here:

```
if (Speed>=1 && Speed=<SpeedLimit)
```

Use <= instead of =<, like this

```
if (Speed >= 1 && Speed <= SpeedLimit)
```

Comment: Yup, Java :-) Just remember the descriptive part (<, >, ! etc.) of the operator always comes first ^^

Comment: Thanks! (Also, sad that I just got banned from asking another question for 3 days D:).